# How to fit a slope modifier in glm (R)

Tags: r, glm

I would like to fit a general linear model of the form:

```
lp = c + (a1+a2*Test)*x
```

Where c is the intercept (to be fitted), a1 is the coefficient for x, and a2 is the modifier to the coefficient of x for the second level of a 2-level factor 'Test' (here coded as a  dummy variable value '1').

So for the first level of the factor 'Test', value 0 of the dummy variable, the slope is a1. For the second level of 'Test', the slope is (a1+a2).

In GenStat, I could fit this as 'x+Test.x' in the Generalized Linear Models menu, and that would give me the estimated values for the coefficients c, a1 and a2 that I want.

In R, I tried the following:

```
glm(y ~ x + Test*x)
```

This gives me the following coefficients: Intercept (c), x, Test, and x:Test.

I think that the 'Test' coefficient is a modifier to the intercept (which I don't want to fit), whilst x:Test is the modifier to the coefficient of x (i.e. a2) that I actually want.

How can I avoid fitting the coefficient for 'Test' in R? Is there an operator that will have the same effect as my use of '.' in GenStat?

Edit: I also tried:

```
glm(y ~ x + offset(Test*x))
```

But that just gives me a fixed offset of the value 'Test*x', it does not fit the coefficient 'a2'.

Comment: I edited my question because I don't think I'd expressed what I was asking clearly enough - does anyone have an answer to my edited question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've managed to find the solution.

The correct operator in R is ':'.

So the code in R is:

glm(y~x+Test:x)

And that gives me fitted coefficients for the intercept, x and Test:x, as required.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know GenStat, but it appears what you are asking for is to have the linear predictor

```
lp = intercept + a1*x + Test*x
```

in algebraic (not model) notation, where `intercept` and `a1` are to be fit, but `Test` and `x` are fixed or observed values.

If that's correct, then the R notation is to describe `Test*x` as an "offset", and fit the model using

```
glm(y ~ x + offset(Test*x))
```

Comment: thank you very much for your response. I turned my factor into a dummy '0'/'1' variable so that I could try 'offset', but from what I can see it's just adding the value 'Test multiplied by x', which is not what I'm trying to do in this case. I am trying to fit the model: 'lp = intercept + (a1+Test.a2).x', where Test is a '0' or '1' dummy variable for the level of my factor. I should have put Test in my equation in my original question - I will edit it!